# Do super rich people have to show their net worth to the public by law?

Tags: law, net-worth

Pretty much all the rich and famous people (i.e billionaires) have their net worths publicly displayed for everyone to see.

Since this is the case, I was wondering if after a certain wealth threshold or after a certain amount of wealth is reached that you have to show your wealth publicly by law. I am just curious if  this is true or is it just a choice of the person with the enormous wealth?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't relate to personal finance

Comment: All questions about the law require a location.

Comment: Where do you get the notion that these individuals have disclosed their net worth? I've always assumed those are just estimates based on known income/assets.

Comment: Whether or not such a law exists is more a question for law.SE rather than personal finance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not by law.

The numbers are mostly guessed - but one thing you should not forget.

Bezos, as example, does not have that much money as his net worth. Most of his net worth is company shares (amazon). THOSE are public - because he is a significant shareholder including seats on the board, his share amount is published public knowledge.

As most of the net worth of most individuals falls into this category, here you have your "law". THAT SAID - a lot is pure guesswork.

Comment: Yeah, that makes a lot of sense. I thought that they disclosed their net worth on purpose, but you changed my mind. Since I could find their net worths on Google, I was under the (false) assumption that was their net worth and therefore I thought they disclosed it. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Money Printer: OTHO, some people inflate their net worth for various reasons.  See for instance the ongoing controversy over Donald Trump's actual net worth.

Answer (score 0):

If a country were to enact a tax on wealth instead of an income tax, then there would be a requirement for some people to disclose to the government their net worth.

Those numbers wouldn't be made public unless that was also a provision of the law.

Most governments make it difficult to share tax information  between government agencies. For example many families have to supply income and wealth information in order to apply for US college aid. Much of the required data is in the hands of the IRS, the numbers only transfer if you explicitly allow it. In fact that tool is only a recent addition.